# Return 404 for invalid routes via nginx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, nginx

I am using nginx with react.
My nginx.conf file

```
server {
listen 80;

location / {
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.html index.htm;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
}
```

As per this config nginx is serving 200 for all routes..
Suppose my routes are

```
  example.com/login
  example.com/landing
```

Now suppose someone enter wrong url

```
 example.com/test
```

In that case i want to throw 404 without landing to application at nginx level itself. Is this possible to handle routing at nginx level and send 404 despite of 200 and than handling at react level.

I found that to restrict any particular route at nginx level we can do it using below code

```
location ^~ /test/ {
    return 404
}
```

But i want to restrict all routes which are invalid for that i used

```
# return 404 for all routes
location / {
    return 404;
}
# define each possible route like this
location /login {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}

location /landing {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```

But after this my application is not loading getting **503 Service Temporarily Unavailable**

First question is it really possible to achieve routing at nginx level if yes what approach i need to take any clue or reference will be of great help.
Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
Please find docker file

```
# Base Image
FROM node:10-alpine AS base
MAINTAINER test@test.com
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Dependencies
FROM base as build
WORKDIR "/usr/src/app"
RUN npm install
RUN npm run test
RUN npm run build

# Web Server
FROM nginx:alpine
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Comment: Can you please post your `Dockerfile`

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram added docker file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, nginx can be used for this.

```
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Just use this one.